# Java HashMap race condition

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, race-condition

I am trying to find out if there is going to be any race condition in this piece of code. If the key weren't 'Thread.currentThread' then I would think yes. But since the thread itself is key, how is it possible to have a race condition? No other thread can possibly update the same key in the HashMap!

```
public class SessionTracker {

     static private final Map<Thread,Session>  threadSessionMap = new HashMap<Thread,Session>();

     static public Session get() {
         return threadSessionMap.get(Thread.currentThread());
     }

     static public void set(Session s) {
         threadSessionMap.put(Thread.currentThread(),s);
     }

     static public void reset() {
         threadSessionMap.remove(Thread.currentThread());
     }
}
```

Comment: Note that there are problems other than the concurrency problems described on the answers. You may have **visibility** problems. (that is, the internal state of the map as seen by one thread might be different from the internal state of the map as seen by another thread). If you call `set` on one thread, and then, later, another thread calls `size()`, it may obtain 0 as the result.

Comment: Anyway, the functionality you're looking for is exactly what is provided by `ThreadLocal`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is yes, there are potential race conditions:

- when **resizing** an HashMap by two threads at the same time
- when **collisions** happens. Collision can happen when two elements map to the same cell even if they have a different hashcode. During the conflict resolution, there can be a race condition and one added key/value pair could be overwritten by another pair inserted by another thread.

To explain better what I mean on the second point, I was looking at the [source code of HashMap in OpenJdk 7](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html)

```
389        int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
390        int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
```

First it calculates an Hash of your key (combining two hash functions), then it maps to a cell with `indexFor`, then it checks if that cell contains the same key or is already occupied by another one. If it's the same key, it just overwrite the value and there is no problem here.

If it's occupied it looks at the next cell and then the next until it finds an empty position and call `addEntry()`, which could even decide to resize the array if the array is more loaded than a certain `loadFactor`.

Our `table` containing the entries is just a vector of `Entry` which holds key and value.

```
146    /**
147     * The table, resized as necessary. Length MUST Always be a power of two.
148     */
149    transient Entry[] table;
```

In a concurrent environment, all sort of evil things can happen, for instance one thread gets a collision for cell number 5 and looks for the next cell (6) and finds it empty.

Meanwhile another thread gets an index of 6 as a result of `indexFor` and both decide to use that cell at the same time, one of the two overwriting the other.

Comment: Thanks. So I am thinking of using 'ConcurrentHashMap' from 'java.util.concurrent' instead.

Comment: better, but [read the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). *The allowed concurrency among update operations is guided by the optional concurrencyLevel constructor argument (default 16), which is used as a hint for internal sizing. The table is internally partitioned to try to permit the indicated number of concurrent updates without contention. Because placement in hash tables is essentially random, the actual concurrency will vary.*

Comment: Hmm, how about if I make the 'HashMap' variable 'threadSessionMap' to be a 'volatile' variable. Will that lock the entire Hashtable?

Comment: @JavaLearner:  No, not by a long shot.  When dealing with multiple threads you *must* lock the data structure, or use one that is designed for concurrency.  Otherwise you risk subtle bugs which will be nearly impossible to track down and haunt you forever...

Comment: @Steven, actually, you can achieve thread-safety without locking through the use of `volatile` fields and *atomic compare-and-set* loops (usually implemented with `AtomicInteger` & friends).

Comment: @JavaLearner: you can use the ConcurrentHashMap. It is safe to be used by multiple threads. The citation above should not discourage you: it just says that ConcurrentHashMap provides a configuration parameter to *improve* on its concurrency -- that is, with the default configuration you can have 100, 1000, as many threads as you want accessing it concurrently. The thing is that there will be some contention (some threads will block).If  you keep under *concurrencyLevel* threads, there's a possibility that no thread will ever block, improving performance.It works in any case

Comment: @BrunoReis: I would say that that falls under a "data structure designed for concurrency", and additionally that if you are asking a question like this, you **should under no circumstances** attempt to design such a thing.  At least not yet :-)  It's devilishly hard to make something that is both correct and faster than the naïve locking solution...

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into specific details of the Hashmap implementations, I would say that there is still the possibility of an error, given the fact that the Hashmap class is not safe for concurrent access.

While I agree that there should be only 1 modification to a **single key** at a time, because you are using currentThread(), there is still the possibility that multiple threads will be modifying the Hashmap concurrently.  Unless you look at the specific implementation, you should not assume that only concurrent access to the same key would cause a problem on the Hashmap, and that concurrent modification to different keys would not.

Imagine a case where two different keys generate to the same hash value, and its easy to see that there can still be errors with concurrent modification.

Comment: Awesome, hadn't thought of hash collisions! I guess using 'ConcurrentHashMap' should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is not a safe thing to do (as the other answers already point out).  A better solution entirely might be to use a [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) which is a more natural way to keep thread local data than using a Map.  It's got a couple of nice features including default values and that the values are removed when a thread terminates.

Comment: How is that going to help me? Can you elaborate?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to associate a session with a particular thread. ThreadLocal provides this kind of storage to a thread. So you could use that to keep the session attached to the thread that owns it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-7-hashmap-vs) written by Pierre Hugues, if you share hashmap between multiple threads, your process may hang and eat all your cpu resource due to infinite looping.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers that your code is not thread safe and while using ConcurrentHashMap would solve your problem, this is the perfect use case for [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).

A short introduction for ThreadLocal:

ThreadLocal will internally hold a different instance of a class for each thread that accesses the ThreadLocal, therefor solving any concurrency issues. Additionally (depending on situation this could be good/bad), the value stored in a ThreadLocal can only be accessed by the thread that populated that value in the first place. If it is the first time the current thread is accessing ThreadLocal, the value will be null.

Simple example of ThreadLocal that holds String values:

```
private static ThreadLocal<String> threadVar = new ThreadLocal<>();

public void foo() {
    String myString = threadVar.get();

    if (myString == null) {
        threadVar.set("some new value");
        myString = threadVar.get();
    }
}
```